# Freezing the crosstab header

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I would want to know how do I freeze the elements inside crosstab header?
When I host it on the server all the crosstab headers move and this is not giving a good user experience in reading the report.

The first four columns including the headers must be frozen and the rest I need it scrollable. I have used `"net.sf.jasperreports.crosstab.floating.headers" value="false"`. But this freezes everything

```
<crosstab>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="8960" height="340" uuid="2002dcd6-e466-46fd-9819-5b2ba30d037d">
                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.headertoolbar.table.name" value=""/>
            </reportElement>
            <crosstabDataset>
                <dataset>
                    <datasetRun subDataset="crosstabdata" uuid="490a0a47-7987-4aed-9e8b-935179a6bee5">
                        <datasetParameter name="Company">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{Company}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="Current_History">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{Current_History}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="Farmer_Survey_Form">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{Farmer_Survey_Form}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="UtcOffSet">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{UtcOffSet}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="Field_Staff"<datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{Field_Staff}]]></datasetParameterExpression></datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="Captured_End_Date">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{Captured_End_Date}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="Captured_Start_Date">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{Captured_Start_Date}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="end_add_utc">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{Captured_End_Date} != null ? DateUtils.addMinutes($P{Captured_End_Date},-$P{UtcOffSet}) : null]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="start_add_utc">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{Captured_Start_Date} != null ? DateUtils.addMinutes($P{Captured_Start_Date},-$P{UtcOffSet}) : null]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="Field_Manager">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{Field_Manager}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="Manager">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{Manager}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                </dataset>
            </crosstabDataset>
            <crosstabHeaderCell>
                <cellContents>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" uuid="198c7076-80b5-11e6-ae22-56b6b6499611"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                        <text><![CDATA[Farmer Code]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="40" uuid="198c72e2-80b5-11e6-ae22-56b6b6499611"/>
                        <box>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                        <text><![CDATA[FarmerName]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="40" uuid="198c73fa-80b5-11e6-ae22-56b6b6499611"/>
                        <box>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                        <text><![CDATA[Village]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="300" y="0" width="100" height="40" uuid="198c74f4-80b5-11e6-ae22-56b6b6499611"/>
                        <box>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                        <text><![CDATA[District]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="400" y="0" width="100" height="40" uuid="198c768e-80b5-11e6-ae22-56b6b6499611"/>
                        <box>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                        <text><![CDATA[State]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="500" y="0" width="100" height="40" uuid="198c779c-80b5-11e6-ae22-56b6b6499611"/>
                        <box>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                        <text><![CDATA[lattitude]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="600" y="0" width="100" height="40" uuid="198c7864-80b5-11e6-ae22-56b6b6499611"/>
                        <box>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                        <text><![CDATA[longitude]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="700" y="0" width="100" height="40" uuid="198c7c42-80b5-11e6-ae22-56b6b6499611"/>
                        <box>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                        <text><![CDATA[CapturedDate]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabHeaderCell>
            <rowGroup name="rank1" width="0">
                <bucket class="java.lang.Double">
                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{rank}]]></bucketExpression>
                </bucket>
                <crosstabRowHeader>
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CH">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="0" height="20" uuid="38d28fa0-f31a-4ca1-ad7f-6fdce4ddc44f"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{rank1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabRowHeader>
                <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                    <cellContents>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="c817dc49-73bd-4871-a8e3-cbb5e2fa2620"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Total rank1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
            </rowGroup>
            <rowGroup name="FarmerCode1" width="100">
                <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{FarmerCode}]]></bucketExpression>
                </bucket>
                <crosstabRowHeader>
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CH">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="168a2718-9f0d-4131-96c9-0c114e3ff8a1"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{FarmerCode1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabRowHeader>
                <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                    <cellContents>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="b65343ca-e938-45e9-8565-aff709bc57e6"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Total FarmerCode1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
            </rowGroup>
            <rowGroup name="FarmerName1" width="100">
                <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{FarmerName}]]></bucketExpression>
                </bucket>
                <crosstabRowHeader>
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CH">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="91af15e5-a5b6-45e9-b2c6-9b2cab1de178"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{FarmerName1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabRowHeader>
                <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                    <cellContents>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="04533255-cfe1-4beb-b8a7-932e15a5f1b1"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Total FarmerName1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
            </rowGroup>
            <rowGroup name="Village1" width="100">
                <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{Village}]]></bucketExpression>
                </bucket>
                <crosstabRowHeader>
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CH">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="d212cc45-73b7-451b-b6de-e0db6537d1f4"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Village1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabRowHeader>
                <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                    <cellContents>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="04135372-ac63-4dba-909f-ba1331e28f22"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Total Village1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
            </rowGroup>
            <rowGroup name="District1" width="100">
                <bucket class="java.lang.Object">
                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{nametoroot}.split(",")[0]]]></bucketExpression>
                </bucket>
                <crosstabRowHeader>
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CH">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="8125d38d-90dd-4eb2-822c-ec1899b8ecc4"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{District1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabRowHeader>
                <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                    <cellContents>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="b00c82d3-eb11-4dce-8946-b16eeca85afd"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Total District1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
            </rowGroup>
            <rowGroup name="State1" width="100">
                <bucket class="java.lang.Object">
                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{nametoroot}.split(",")[1]]]></bucketExpression>
                </bucket>
                <crosstabRowHeader>
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CH">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="9fc6f224-0118-4e96-bd44-2e1e8df36aae"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{State1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabRowHeader>
                <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                    <cellContents>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="a3872cc6-af19-4e72-85f4-7775fa8d768b"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Total State1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
            </rowGroup>
            <rowGroup name="lattitude1" width="100">
                <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{lattitude}]]></bucketExpression>
                </bucket>
                <crosstabRowHeader>
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CH">
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="e58014c1-039b-45aa-8069-6471ab245b8f"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{lattitude1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabRowHeader>
                <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                    <cellContents>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="06946b02-a585-4eda-ad54-5f85501a5fa9"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Total lattitude1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
            </rowGroup>
            <rowGroup name="longitude1" width="100">
                <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{longitude}]]></bucketExpression>
                </bucket>
                <crosstabRowHeader>
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CH">
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="0108e390-490f-4a9e-aa7a-ac7de7350a81"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{longitude1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabRowHeader>
                <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                    <cellContents>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="d8154762-5754-4b4b-b9b4-7fdfbd486f0e"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Total longitude1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
            </rowGroup>
            <rowGroup name="CapturedDate1" width="100">
                <bucket class="java.sql.Timestamp">
                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{CapturedDate}]]></bucketExpression>
                </bucket>
                <crosstabRowHeader>
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CH">
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="3f181f8a-2013-4b6b-a4ea-ba939afe6bc4"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{CapturedDate1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabRowHeader>
                <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                    <cellContents>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="c16fa1e1-b80c-4728-8877-0fcc3364a98a"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Total CapturedDate1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
            </rowGroup>
            <columnGroup name="FormName1" height="20">
                <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{FormName}]]></bucketExpression>
                </bucket>
                <crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CH">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="20" uuid="7d671d6b-422a-4b00-b536-a6e6f846d88f">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{FormName1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabColumnHeader>
                <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                    <cellContents>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="341b77e7-f4ac-4352-81e5-f8fa5a8af442"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Total FormName1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
            </columnGroup>
            <columnGroup name="Attribute1" height="20">
                <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{Attribute}]]></bucketExpression>
                </bucket>
                <crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CH">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="20" uuid="060b8f03-d7fa-492f-a3fb-08ee3dafdb5a">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attribute1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabColumnHeader>
                <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                    <cellContents>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="99185f30-74d4-4ae5-aa3e-1f4b6cc8eed2"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Total Attribute1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
            </columnGroup>
            <measure name="Attributevalue_MEASURE1" class="java.lang.String">
                <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{Attributevalue}]]></measureExpression>
            </measure>
            <crosstabCell width="200" height="20">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CD">
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="20" uuid="ba8179f7-039a-4aac-92c4-ff546113e544">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" columnTotalGroup="FormName1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CT">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="1d9f4518-7bd9-494e-b061-844f540d772e"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" columnTotalGroup="Attribute1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CG">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="7802e2dd-b2b4-401b-b2d4-1ce1be3e790b"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="rank1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CT">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="878597c2-4e38-4a57-9a84-912a88c48289"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="rank1" columnTotalGroup="FormName1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CT">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="5d579afa-0c94-4227-a58d-962e81329eee"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="rank1" columnTotalGroup="Attribute1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CT">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="eed44e6c-85d8-454e-9a34-23a5c93f4acb"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="FarmerCode1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CG">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="ac0edef8-c7ec-4d4f-9fd7-f867bce25f73"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="FarmerCode1" columnTotalGroup="FormName1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CT">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="08af03ed-dd78-40d1-aba2-fad2c53ed691"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="FarmerCode1" columnTotalGroup="Attribute1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CG">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="ff140bb6-c126-45e7-ac73-78a77e9f312b"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="FarmerName1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CG">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="374b45ee-e9d1-405c-9045-aaeecd9ae780"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="FarmerName1" columnTotalGroup="FormName1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CT">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="c101c960-296a-4984-a36f-106922d4b1ca"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="FarmerName1" columnTotalGroup="Attribute1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CG">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="a8b25a61-6cdb-4ef4-b9cd-87429d7266a2"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="Village1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CG">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="fc053106-7025-4416-9544-18c6a2f6720b"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="Village1" columnTotalGroup="FormName1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CT">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="de5e0572-f8e8-438a-82b8-f6132c07a663"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="Village1" columnTotalGroup="Attribute1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CG">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="e7c102ea-669b-4cd7-8fa3-84d59e7a7d93"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="District1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CG">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="229b2d92-3515-44ce-b120-a9da7263f924"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="District1" columnTotalGroup="FormName1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CT">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="8fe0fafd-14fb-4dfe-87ae-813285f16cc2"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="District1" columnTotalGroup="Attribute1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CG">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="35fb8c8b-f214-4416-8e8e-c8fc19a848c8"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="State1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CG">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="822a8aff-a259-4ef2-a7ff-4e9089d31354"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="State1" columnTotalGroup="FormName1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CT">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="775feca9-2743-4a2f-9cd1-415180acc41e"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="State1" columnTotalGroup="Attribute1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CG">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="ee04875d-82db-4cf9-b7d0-183c44fe6a87"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="lattitude1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CG">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="64232cdc-01c6-4973-9efa-0724307e71de"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="lattitude1" columnTotalGroup="FormName1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CT">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="8d46bd61-bfbc-495a-95ae-b35cb8c870b8"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="lattitude1" columnTotalGroup="Attribute1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CG">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="2724982d-83bb-4734-8b29-617eb0e9f93d"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="longitude1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CG">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="9e2225ac-67e5-4c98-9007-ea5b9cd8e68e"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="longitude1" columnTotalGroup="FormName1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CT">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="17a2a9d9-a57a-48a9-adba-94ef365fac2b"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="longitude1" columnTotalGroup="Attribute1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CG">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="fdd9bf19-5bf7-49d1-b4ac-9a11581b6c15"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="CapturedDate1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CG">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="fcab56b2-9ff2-41ef-80b7-b289ccef15c6"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="CapturedDate1" columnTotalGroup="FormName1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CT">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="dc9ca09a-6289-4a2b-afcc-7824754233f0"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="CapturedDate1" columnTotalGroup="Attribute1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 3_CG">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="1f74ff2e-adb5-4779-be51-aad537d57e17"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Attributevalue_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
        </crosstab>
```

Any ideas on this would be very helpful

Comment: What do you mean by: _I have used "net.sf.jasperreports.crosstab.floating.headers" value="false". But this freezes everything_ ?

Comment: Like I said, with the mentioned property, the entire table is frozen meaning I am unable to scroll the details horizontally while keeping the first 4 columns frozen. I want to know how would I be able to keep the first 4 columns not movable and the rest of the details horizontally scrollable?

Comment: In the case of crosstabs and tables, `floating` headers mean `fixed` or `frozen` headers and are enabled by default. That is why it is unclear how can that property set to `false` freeze everything since it is supposed to unfreeze(cancel the floating of) the crosstab column/row headers. However, there are cases(due to the design of the crosstab) when floating headers do not work as expected. A complete sample that reproduces the issue might come in handy.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. How do I post my entire code? I keep getting the exceed character limit error when I try to edit my main post and paste the code?

Comment: You could create a Github gist, paste the code there then add the link here. Or use any other upload service and link it here.

Comment: Thank you. Please do look at the code details in the link https://gist.github.com/RathiMittha/3904ae18d23e19d874d050db31dfbccf